# Node.js. Try catch doesn't work in the case of readline.question

Tags: javascript, node.js, error-handling, try-catch

The catch block doesn't handle the "ERROR". The app fails with the 'Unhandled Error' exception.
Why it happens and how to make it work | handle it correctly?

```
 function write() {
  try {
    rl.question('> ', (line: string) => {
      throw "ERROR"
      // caller(line)
    });
  } catch (e) {
    console.log('local level')
    console.log(`Error -> ${e}`);
  }

}

try {
  write();
} catch (e) {
  console.log('global level')
}
```

Thanks for any help. Kind Regard.

P.S. Update

My code is a synchronous chain of functions. Basically it looks like:

```
function validateArg(arg) { if (!arg) throw "Missed arg" }

function caller(arg) {
  validateArg(arg) // it should throw an error if no arg

  ...do some with arg
}
```

and inside *readline* I'm calling it. I want to read the data, handle it and provide some results. 
I'd like to catch an error that might come from inside of the code and prevent the app from failing. I thought to do it via global **tr-catch**

Comment: Move your `try/catch` block inside the callback function.

Comment: By the time the callback throws the error, the enclosing block with the `try`-`catch` is out of scope. It's unclear what this code is supposed to do, though, so without more context it's difficult to recommend a course of action. Typically, the API would place the error as the first parameter to the callback, "nodebacks", but there are other ways to do this. Is this your API or someone else's? If the latter, check their docs.

Comment: Hi Marc and ggorlen. Thanks for your answers. I really missed fact that the callback is outside of scope. My API is a synchronous functions chain so I just want to catch any error that can happen inside the API. Is it possible to do it somehow globally or the callback is the only 1 possible way? Thanks!

Comment: "*My code is a synchronous chain of functions*" - no, it's not. It uses `readline`, which makes it asynchronous. To use `try`/`catch`, use promises with readline and `async`/`await` syntax.

Comment: Hi Bergi. Thanks for your notice. I didn't explain it well, sorry. I knew that the redline async stuff. I mentioned 'my code' I called in the readline function. It's synchronous =)